# How to run blender on webserver?

Tags: python, blender

I have a small script (model convertation), and this script works perfectly on local Win7 x64. I run it from command line

```
C:\SOFT\blender-2.79-windows64\blender.exe --debug-all --background --python myscript.py
```

Script takes one file, then converts it to another format.
I want to run this script on webserver.
I mean, i want to put blender on webhosting, and execute script directly on webhosting.

Questions:

1. Which version of Blender i should use(Linux?)?
2. What will be my syntax on hosting?

Comment: 1.: Does your webserver run on linux? Then a linux-version, obviously. 2.: The same.

Comment: What do you mean by "put on webhosting"? Do you want a web application that can run your Blender script? What does your hosting environment look like? There currently aren't enough details to answer the question.

Comment: I want converter *.obj ->*.dae format on my site. User upload obj-model, and my blender script makes dae file. Very simple.

Comment: You need provide information about your webserver. This only works if you have a root server. Did you check if there are other solutions to convert your model, e.g. JS?

Comment: "Other solutions" not suitable, because i planned to extend functional.  "Information about webserver" - i need to know capabilities, and after that i request these capabilities from webhoster. Most of hosters offers python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to arrange some hosting, the cheaper host-managed shared web hosting options will rarely install non-web related software such as blender. This means you will need to look at having a linux server that you setup and manage yourself (or you pay someone to do it for you). The most common option these days is using the cloud. Most cloud providers offer pre-installed linux systems, so you just have to install the specific software you use, such as apache, php, blender. depending on which linux flavour you use it will be something like `sudo apt-get install apache2 php blender`

Once you have a server setup, get the path for blender -

```
% where blender
/usr/local/bin/blender
```

You then use that path instead of the windows `C:\SOFT\blender-2.79-windows64\blender.exe`.

In your script you may need to adjust the use of paths in a similar way, [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) is an easy way to join paths in a cross-platform way, the newer [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) can also be used.

The linux equivelant of your example would be something like -

```
/usr/local/bin/blender --debug-all --background --python /home/joe/myscript.py
```

Comment: I asked my hoster "Is it possible to launch Blender on hosting?".
He answers "I don't know, you should try run it on our Docker enviroment." (Hoster has Docker enviroment).
So, Docker is new for me. Anyway i've found  Docker images of Blender, but what is the workflow (commands) to operate with it?
I mean to what location i must upload this image, and what commands i must send to operate?   Also you told me, that blender "needs to install". So Blender for Linux is portable, and i was told that maybe i don't need Docker, and Blender launches by itself (if i'll send command via php)